# Browsing into a folder in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I ssh to the debvox that it for Hadoop and if I saay `hadoop fs -ls` I get a lot of files including

```
drwxr-xr-x   - root hadoop          0 2013-07-11 17:49 sandeep
drwxr-xr-x   - root hadoop          0 2013-04-10 14:13 testprocedure
drwxr-xr-x   - root hadoop          0 2013-04-03 13:56 tmp
```

I need to go inside that tmp folder, took a look at Hadoop shell commands in here but still didn't find the command for it. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html

So what's the command to go to that folder?

[image]

Comment: Additionally I'd like to mention that you can use muCommander for browsing HDFS. This patch works with all Hadoop distributions: https://github.com/lbendig/mucommander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the directory name, as follows:

`hadoop fs -ls tmp`

Sample output from my Demo VM:

`hadoop fs -ls`

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls
Found 12 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         46 2013-06-18 21:18 /user/cloudera/FileWrite.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         13 2013-06-18 15:34 /user/cloudera/HelloWorld.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2013-07-01 22:07 /user/cloudera/hiveext
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-06-12 15:10 /user/cloudera/input
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup        176 2013-06-18 23:07 /user/cloudera/input_data.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-09-06 15:44 /user/cloudera/movies_input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-09-06 17:02 /user/cloudera/movies_output
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-09-06 14:53 /user/cloudera/output
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2013-07-01 23:45 /user/cloudera/sample_external_input
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         16 2012-06-14 01:39 /user/cloudera/test.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-06-13 00:00 /user/cloudera/weather_input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2012-06-13 15:13 /user/cloudera/weather_output
```

When I specify a directory `hadoop fs -ls sample_external_input`:

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls sample_external_input
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         61 2013-07-01 23:17 /user/cloudera/sample_external_input/sample_external_data.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         13 2013-07-01 23:18 /user/cloudera/sample_external_input/sample_external_data2.txt
```

Comment: ok thanks, so that takes in to inside the tmp folder?  because from what it shows on commandline it doesn't look like it is there... I can update my question with a screen shot of it if needed.

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark from your screen shot, I can see that it is showing you the contents of the temp folder. `tmp/chris` and `tmp/personAlias` are within tmp directory right?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark, also check out my edit, showing output from my demo VM

Answer (score 2):

> I need to go inside that tmp folder, took a look at Hadoop shell
>   commands in here but still didn't find the command for it.
>   http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html

There is nothing like **cd** which can take us inside a directory. So you can't go to that folder like you can do in your local FS. You could probably use **ls** a others have suggested, but that just list the content inside a directory and doesn't take you to that directory. If you really want to go inside a particular directory, you could make use of the HDFS WebUI. You can point your web browser to **NameNode_Machine:50070** to go there. It allows you to browse the entire HDFS. You can view and download the files as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify nothing after `-ls`, then the folders will be those in your "home" directory. If you want to give a path relative to your home folder, you can do so

```
hadoop fs ls tmp/someTmpStuff
```

(assuming tmp is a folder in your home directory ) or use a fully qualified path

```
hadoop fs ls /user/me/tmp/someTmpStuff
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if you have hadoop access or not. if yes then use command :

```
[yourhost]$ hadoop fs -ls /dir1/
```

It will list directory or file which is inside **dir1**